# Can we use 'one of the' for the plural? whch sentense is correct of the following?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which sentence is correct?

> Flour and meat are the **one of the** most used food ingredients in the world.
>
> Flour and meat are **two of the** most used food ingredients in the world.

Comment: Two items can't be _one_ ingredient! Obviously it's _two_ - or you could say they are _among the most used ingredients_.

Answer (score 1):

Flour and meat are two different ingredients, so you have to use the plural.

As such, only the second sentence is correct:

> ✔ Flour and meat **are** two of the most used food **ingredients** in the world.

However, it's also possible to rephrase the first sentence in a way that preserves some of its sense while having it be grammatical:

> ✔ Flour and meat **are** ***among*** the most used food **ingredients** in the world.